# Mirror Modifier Overlapping Faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I am trying to model something and when I mirror it, the faces in the middle overlap. Should I just move the mirrored faces or am I doing something wrong? This is what it looks like after I apply the modifier.
[image]

I don't want the band down the middle. The only option I changed in the modifier section was the axis it mirrored over. I am using Blender Render as well.

Comment: Is clipping turned on?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on "clipping" in the mirror modifier stack. Adjust the threshold or go into edit mode and select the mesh, move it until the centre vertices snaps in place.

Comment: I have had clipping on and it didn't help. I went into edit mode and did that, but what I really want to know now is how to merge the side into one object. When I subdivide, it treats each side like a different object.

Answer (score 2):

Check clipping. This should fix your problem.
Alternately, you could use Shift+S to move the 3D cursor to your mesh's origin, then left a bit. Key Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C (yes, really) and select Origin to 3D cursor. This will reallign your line of symmetry.

Comment: I have had clipping on and it didn't help. I went into edit mode and did that, but what I really want to know now is how to merge the side into one object. When I subdivide, it treats each side like a different object.

Comment: If you want to merge both sides, try moving the origin a bit more so that there is a visible gap between the two halves of your mesh. Then apply the mirror modifier, select both edge loops bordering the gap, key "W" and select bridge edge loops. Your subserf should work fine now.