# Why mirroring doesn't seem to work?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

1. I did mirroring but as you can see, there's a line dividing face into half which I don't want. How should I fix this?

Comment: You need to place the object's origin on the axis of symmetry Read the related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/mirror-modifier-is-not-working-no-mirrored-object and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46336/mirror-modifier-overlapping-faces and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57743/mirror-modifier-making-verticies-overlap

Comment: related also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6063/subsurf-and-mirror-modifier-creating-a-split-in-mesh

Comment: u know what? I just fixed it!

Comment: please write an asnwer detailing how you fixed it, so that others with a similar problems can learn from your experience.