# Mirroring this object gives unwanted results

Tags: modeling

[image: Elephant Problem]

Ive been trying to follow this tutorial but i got lost...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JjW6r10Mlqs

The mirror is inverted... I want it to be a closed object, not open from both sides.

Comment: What are the "wanted" results?

Comment: Aslo related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46336/mirror-modifier-overlapping-faces

Comment: The mirror is inverted... I want it to be a closed object, not open from both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Make the origin of your object to be any of the edges of an open wall

[image]

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - Snap

To move the 3d cursor to the selected edge.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Origin

To move the origin of the object to the location of the 3D cursor.

Comment: How do i make those button images for future references? :P I'm a newbie here.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style

Comment: huh? cant seem to find a "how to do it" just "how you SHOULD do it". Kinda confusing

Comment: Click on the edit link in your answer to see how it is done.Then read:  read https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/409/1853